# How to remove borders around fieldset containing radio buttons in html and css?

Tags: html, css

So I'm pretty new to HTML and CSS in general and I've been struggling to remove the white borders around my radio group. But I'm not sure how to remove them, I've also tried playing around with CSS to solve it but to no avail. Thanks in advance for helping.

What I'm talking about
[image: What I'm talking about]
Here's the HTML I'm using.

```html
<fieldset id="group2">
  Do you play games on a daily basis?
  </br>
  <label for="yes">Yes</label>
  <input type="radio" value="Yes" name="yes">
  <label for="no">No</label>
  <input type="radio" value="No" name="no">
</fieldset>
```

Comment: `<fieldset>` is kinda old-fashioned, it was years I didn't see one. Are you sure you wanna use it? Modern CSS has better ways for grouping inputs

Comment: @CristianTraìna Well,I'm following freeCodeCamp's curriculum and I used that for a project so I thought it was the only way, lol. What would the Modern CSS way be for grouping inputs?

Comment: The same solutions used for layouts, such as grid, flexbox, display/inline. I'm sure that FreeCodeCamp covers also them

Comment: @CristianTraìna Ahhh ok, I got a bit confused when you said Modern CSS.Yeah,it does cover it tho,lol. I'll look into it more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add below css :

```css
fieldset {
  border: 0;
}
```